# AS3 Loaded swfs with timeline animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks, air

I have a shell that i have built in AIR that loads external swfs and cycles through them. this is a shell that i have reused many times. This round though i have inserted timeline animations into the loaded swfs. But now i see my memory usage increasing far more rapidly than in versions i have used that did not have timeline animations.

This is going to a convention where the application will be running for many hours and i fear it will crash.

Does anybody know any smart process I could use to prevent such an increase in memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

That memory consumption is caused by elements being stored in memory throughout your animation, when that is no longer in use it will be garbage collected. If you know when it is no longer using that animation you can wait for it to be garbage collected, or invoke it using :

```
System.gc();
```

Otherwise, converting your animations to bitmaps or using sprite sheets are going to be your best resolution. If you have CS6 you can right click and export as a sprite sheet, otherwise you can look into using things like:

- [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)
- [Zoë](http://www.createjs.com/#!/Zoe)